# Viewflow is missing the process data and participant tab of an activity

Tags: k2-blackpearl

Using K2 Five workflow designer I deployed a new workflow. And when I see the viewflow of an instance I couldn't get the activity details, process data tab and participant tab (for client task)

But for K2 4.7 WF instance's viewflow shows the above details still in the K2 Five version.

Do we have an option to view the details in viewflow? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can drill down to Activity and Event details using Reports tab in K2 Management or K2 Workspace.

Drilling down in Process Activities and Events is currently not possible in K2 Five workflows, but it is on the roadmap. I'll update this answer when it gets released.